# Random BAD_ACCESS and "not recognized selector"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

Hey, I'm a beginner in Objective C, and my .NET and Java years have rusted my memory management skills, so it's very likely I'm missing something here.

I am building an iPad app. The main view is a SplitView with a TableView on the left, and the detail view contains another TableView. The loading of the latter with data has been commented out in an attempt to single out my problem.

The app seems to work fine (has to fetch data from a .NET WS and parse it into the table), but at random times I receive a BAD_ACCESS or a "selector not recognized" errors.

The selector not recognized error I get here:

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *) response {
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
```

This piece of code I'm sure most of you know about, I got it from all samples I found online and in books to send a web request.

Beats me why it says it does not recognize the setLength selector, webData is defined as

```
NSMutableData *webData;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not allocate your webData object either with

```
NSMutableData* webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];
```

or

```
NSMutableData* webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
```

then the webData object will most likely be autoreleased during one of the context switches from the NSURLConnection message that you allocated it in (probably `connection:didReceiveData:`) to the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` message.

Any object that you do not `alloc` or explicitly `retain` is likely to be deallocated during scope changes, even if it is a member variable of your class.

Comment: I see. The randomness of the deallocation does indeed fit autoreleasing as the source problem. This is the code where I instanciate webData:  conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self]; So I do retain it, or is it still a problem?
if (conn) {
webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}

Comment: You are retaining webData, so autorelease shouldn't be your problem here.  It's not obvious what the problem is based on your updated information.  I suggest two changes - instead of using `if(conn)` to allocate your webData object, move the line to your connection:didReceiveData: NSURLConnection delegate message, and modify it to `if( webData == nil ) webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048];` and second, where you release web data, change it to `[webData release], webData = nil;`

Comment: I highly recommend always setting released objects to nil immediately after releasing them.  This is because `[webData release]; [webData getLength];` will always result in a crash but `[webData release], webData = nil; [webData getLength];` will not.

Comment: Care to elaborate? how is that not the same? I mean, if the ref count is 1, when I send the release message, webData should deallocate itself and be set to nil, is this not correct?

Comment: `release` does not set the released object to nil, it only frees the memory used by the object.  When you say `[webData release]` you are telling the autorelease pool that you have no use for webData anymore, but the NSMutableData* webData still references a particular location in memory.  When you say `webData = nil` you are clearing the memory reference so that the old webData object is no longer reachable.  This matters because Obj-C will try to call a message on a deallocated object (resulting in a seg fault).  `[nil doAnyMessage];` will never result in a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you aren't creating the NSMutableData correctly. I expect you have code that looks like

```
webData = [NSMutableData data];
```

This is going to give you an autoreleased object, and yet you're storing it in an ivar. You need to take ownership of the object when storing it in an ivar. In your case, the simplest way is just to skip the convenience method and go with alloc/init:

```
webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
```

For more details, read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Thank you, will read your link. In the meantime, this is what I use: webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be very usual (not only beginners) error, when connection is not cancels in `dealloc` or `viewWillDisappear`. When you are leaving the controller, you should cancel all connection, timers, etc, created by the controller, to prevent them from calling delegate methods or selectors on deallocated controller objects.

Comment: I am not "leaving" the controller. The connection is being released when done. -(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
NSLog(@“DONE. Received Bytes: %d”, [webData length]);
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]
initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]
length:[webData length]
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//---shows the XML---
NSLog(theXML);
[theXML release];
[connection release];
[webData release];
}

Comment: In that case please provide all the related code and stack trace on crash

Comment: In any case please ensure you are calling `cancel` method in `dealloc` and `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like webData is being deallocated and replaced with some other object. Make sure you retain it if you don't use alloc/init or mutableCopy to get it.

Comment: I use: webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];